# How to save (serialize) com.here.sdk.routing.Route instance in HERE SDK Navigate Edition (4.13.2.0)

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, maps, here-api

Old HERE SDK premium ver:

val result = Route ?.let(RouteImpl::b)?.data ?: byteArrayOf()  // here we can save Route instance to SharedPrefs

Route = SharedPrefs.getString(PREFS_ROUTE_KEY, null)?.let { Base64.decode(it, Base64.DEFAULT) }?.let(RouteImpl::a)?.route   // here we can fetch Route instance from SharedPrefs

I've tried to  save Route object using that:
`Gson().toJson(Route)`

and fetch it using that:
`val type = object : TypeToken<Route>() {}.type Route = Gson().fromJson<Route>(currentRouteString, type)`

But in new HERE SDK Navigate Edition I've not found any serialization for Route.

How to save (serialize) com.here.sdk.routing.Route  instance in HERE SDK Navigate Edition?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, HERE SDK does not provide serialization. What you can try is to store the route shape and import the route later. Or use the route handle - https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.13.5.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#import-routes-from-other-services

Anyway, storing a route permanently is not what users should do, because a route contains real-time events like traffic etc. So, calculating a route when needed is recommended.

Comment: thanks i have done like that, but using just current location and endpoit coordinates